# MySQL left join return return only one row

Tags: mysql, left-join

I am trying to find previous flight from the historical flight table, i have only 1 historical table wit tail number of plane and scheduled date departure in it, i want to make a new table with information of previous flight from that plane, below is example of the table

Original Table :

```
|flight number|scheduled departure flight|
| A           | 1 Jan 2018 10:00         |
| A           | 1 Jan 2018 19:00         |
| B           | 1 Jan 2018 11:00         |
| B           | 1 Jan 2018 19:00         |
| B           | 1 Jan 2018 21:00         |
```

Result expected :

```
|flight number|scheduled departure flight| previous scheduled departure |
| A           | 1 Jan 2018 10:00         | NULL                         |
| A           | 1 Jan 2018 19:00         | 1 Jan 10:00                  |
| B           | 1 Jan 2018 11:00         | NULL                         |
| B           | 1 Jan 2018 19:00         | 1 Jan 2018 11:00             |
| B           | 1 Jan 2018 21:00         | 1 jan 2018 19:00             |
```

i have been working on it for a day, appreciate any help from you

Comment: Please, put your MySQL code and the error or result that you are receiving in order to help you. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `LAG` window function, but which support mysql version higher than 8.0

You can try to use a subquery to make a `lag` window function.

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

**Query #1**

```
SELECT `flight number`,
       `scheduled departure flight`,
       (select `scheduled departure flight` 
       from T tt
       where t1.`scheduled departure flight` > tt.`scheduled departure flight`
       AND t1.`flight number` = tt.`flight number`
       order by tt.`scheduled departure flight` desc
       limit 1
       ) 'previous scheduled departure'
FROM T t1;

| flight number | scheduled departure flight | previous scheduled departure |
| ------------- | -------------------------- | ---------------------------- |
| A             | 2018-06-01 10:00:00        |                              |
| A             | 2018-06-01 19:00:00        | 2018-06-01 10:00:00          |
| B             | 2018-06-01 11:00:00        |                              |
| B             | 2018-06-01 19:00:00        | 2018-06-01 11:00:00          |
| B             | 2018-06-01 21:00:00        | 2018-06-01 19:00:00          |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/o5VAPqdodvKZCNnjuVb9go/0)

If your mysql version support `LAG` you can try this.

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE T(
   `flight number` varchar(5),
    `scheduled departure flight` datetime
);



INSERT INTO T VALUES ('A','2018-06-01 10:00');
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('A','2018-06-01 19:00');
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('B','2018-06-01 11:00');
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('B','2018-06-01 19:00');
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('B','2018-06-01 21:00');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT `flight number`,
       `scheduled departure flight`,
       LAG(`scheduled departure flight`) OVER(PARTITION BY  `flight number` ORDER BY `scheduled departure flight`) 'previous scheduled departure'
FROM T t1;
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/o5VAPqdodvKZCNnjuVb9go/1)

Comment: thankyou, i need to extract not only the date, but also all the information from previous flight , how to add another column in the result ?

Comment: What do your mean `information`? I didn't see this column.

Comment: actually there is another information in the table and i forgot to put it in the question

Comment: i just repeat the query for another information and it work, thanks